# VS Code Terminal- Split for client and server folder

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to split the terminal of VSCode into two parts and run code(git command) of client and server in both individuals terminals.

[image]

I have attached an image pls see I have to achieve that only means run both folders in two terminals. I have to achieve that only.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal view, press the <kbd>+</kbd> icon to add a new terminal, select a directory to use. Once you have multiple terminal sessions, you'll see that sidebar menu listing them. Click and drag one into whatever area you wish it to occupy.

Alternatively, you can look at using a [terminal multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer), but that's not what's being used in the screenshot you show.